# Fazer um botão mostrar e esconder uma <ul> em Js

Tags: javascript, div, dom

Boa tarde, o meu objetivo é fazer com que um botão ao ser clicado mostre uma div que contém uma ul, que por default essa ul estará escondida. Até agora consegui fazer com que a ul sumisse, mas não consegui fazer com que ao clicar novamente no botão a div seja mostrada novamente. Segue meu código:

```js
const lista = document.querySelector(".lista");
const botao = document.querySelector("[data-botao]").addEventListener("click", (evento)=>{
  let relatedDiv = lista.setAttribute("style","display: none");
  relatedDiv = (evento) =>  lista.toggleAttribute('slow')
})
```

o que estou errando?

Comment: poderia incluir o html, para ver de onde esta capturando assim podera ter a mesma referencia do arquivo que esta usando :)    ?

Answer (score -2):

Acho que seria isso que você precisaria:

```js
   // JS
   const lista = document.querySelector(".lista");
   const botao = document.querySelector("[data-botao]")
   botao.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
           
   // evento.preventDefault() opcional para não dar o refresh na tela 

   let relatedDiv = lista.classList.toggle('toggle')
   relatedDiv = (evento) =>  lista.toggleAttribute('slow')
})
```

```css
/* CSS */
.toggle {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<ul>
   <li class="lista">op 1</li>
   <li>op 2</li>
</ul>

<button data-botao>
   ESCONDER
</button>
```